# Use existing data streams to segment data from each individual app

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics

From the old version of analytics I have 1 property with many data streams.
Each data stream represents 1 Android app.

[image]

The reports are not relevant as they aggregate all data streams with no way to segment each individual app.

How can I get a separate reporting for each app using the same data streams i.s. WITHOUT creating new firebase config files.

I have already tried to create a new property but when adding the datastream, there is no way to use an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out a way to get what I need:
In a new report, click All users, then the Audience Name should be Stream ID and then the Dimension Value should be the app you want the report from.